# Django - error_403() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exception'

Tags: python, django

When the user is not allowed to see the contents of the instance, when the PermissionDenied exception was thrown, instead of forwarding it to the 404.html template, it has an error.

DetailView:

```
class OccurrenceDetail(OccurrenceModel, BaseDetailViewWithLogin):
    permission_required = ('occurrences.see_occurrence')

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        perm = self.request.user.has_perm(self.permission_required)
        obj = super(OccurrenceDetail, self).get_object(queryset=queryset)
        if not perm:
            raise PermissionDenied()
        return obj
```

Urls:

```
handler403 = 'apps_core.core.views.error_403'
```

Views:

```
def error_403(request):
    data = {}
    return render(request,'errors/403.html', data)
```

Comment: The error encountered might be useful information

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`403` error view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view) expects a second argument, which is the raised exception.

To solve it, you can change your code to:

```
def error_403(request, exception):
    ...
```

or something more general

```
def error_403(request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Comment: How to pass in permission codes to the context in the function `error_403` that was called on permission error so that these could to be displayed in the **error page**? Thanks.

Comment: @shaan I have found no way to show in the template which missing permission raised the `PermissionDenied` exception.

Comment: Thanks sir. I was off the grid (for _sometime_) so saw your reply very late. It is really disheartening to come to term with this. I had tried to use Django sessions as well but somehow it's very buggy, the data gets displayed intermittently. So next I thought why not use the Django `permission_denied_message`. But here also I am coming up against major issues. If you could spare some time, will you check my query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63167348/how-to-display-permission-denied-message-in-custom-403-html-page-in-django)? Thanks a lot.